# Raspberry Pi as a internet radio server?

Tags: raspbian, audio, streaming

I'm looking for a way to stream audio mp3's and spotify to my internet radio from my Pi. I've have looked and can only find things that play it on the Pi. I also need a way of controlling what's being play ethier by a web page or an app.

Comment: what have you tried? you need some more details here, tell us what model of internet radio you have etc..

Comment: make magize had an article on the Pi as a pirate radio server. You can broadcast FM on pin 14. For internet radio, I have used icecast, and SOAP, though I have never used those on a Pi.  http://makezine.com/projects/make-38-cameras-and-av/raspberry-pirate-radio/

Answer (score 2):

I can't say I know anything about Spotify so I'll leave that part for someone else. For streaming audio to an Internet radio you'll need a DLNA server (most "Internet capable" radios that I'm aware of act as DLNA clients). A couple of decent choices are MediaTomb and miniDLNA; these are both packaged for Raspbian so installing them is trivial with apt.

So, to install a DLNA server (I'll use MediaTomb here as it's what I'm most familiar with):

```
$ sudo apt-get install mediatomb
```

That'll get MediaTomb installed and started. Next you want to make sure that you media is under a directory accessible to the newly created `mediatomb` user. I'll assume that your media is under `/mnt/media`. If this location is a Linux file-system (i.e. *not* a FAT formatted USB hard drive) then you can do:

```
$ sudo chgrp -R mediatomb /mnt/media
```

If it's not a Linux file-system (i.e. if it *is* a FAT formatted USB hard drive) then it's probably mounted in such a way that all users can read everything. You can check whether the `mediatomb` user can read the directory like so:

```
$ sudo -u mediatomb ls /mnt/media
```

If you see the contents of the directory, great! If you get something like "Permission denied" then you'll need to figure out how to mount the file-system in such a way that the `mediatomb` user (or all users) can read it. That'll probably involve fiddling with settings in `/etc/fstab` which is rather beyond the scope of this answer.

Assuming you've got your media accessible, we now need to configure MediaTomb to tell it where to look for media. Fire up your favourite text editor (you might prefer nano here ;):

```
$ sudo vim /etc/mediatomb/config.xml
```

You'll want to add an `<autoscan>` section which describes where MediaTomb should look for media files. I tend to add this just before `<mappings>` (it needs to be within the `<import>` element). For example, assuming all your media is under `/mnt/media` (which might be an external USB hard drive) this segment of the config file should wind up looking like the following:

```
...
<import hidden-files="no">
  <scripting script-charset="UTF-8">
    <common-script>/usr/share/mediatomb/js/common.js</common-script>
    <playlist-script>/usr/share/mediatomb/js/playlists.js</playlist-script>
    <virtual-layout type="builtin">
      <import-script>/usr/share/mediatomb/js/import.js</import-script>
      <dvd-script>/usr/share/mediatomb/js/import-dvd.js</dvd-script>
    </virtual-layout>
  </scripting>

  <!-- This is the chunk to add -->
  <autoscan use-inotify="auto">
    <directory location="/mnt/media" mode="inotify" recursive="yes" />
  </autoscan>

  <mappings>
    <extension-mimetype ignore-unknown="no">
      <map from="mp3" to="audio/mpeg"/>
      <map from="ogg" to="application/ogg"/>
      <map from="asf" to="video/x-ms-asf"/>
      <map from="asx" to="video/x-ms-asf"/>
...
```

Finally, restart MediaTomb:

```
$ sudo service mediatomb restart
```

You should see MediaTomb appear as a source pretty quickly on any DLNA clients on your network (Internet radios, PS3s, XBMC installations, BubbleUPNP on Android, etc. etc.) but it might take a few minutes for media to appear under the source. MediaTomb has to index stuff before it makes it available for streaming, hence the delay.